# How to make a static file available on Github Pages build folder

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

In my `PokeList` class, I have the following code

```js
componentDidMount() {
  fetch('./pokedex.json')
    .then( response => {
      if (response.ok) {
        return response.json()
      }
      throw response
    }).then (data => {
      console.log(data)
      // this.setState({pokeDex: data})
    }).catch (error => {
      console.error("An error occurred: ", error)
    }).finally(() => {
      this.setState({loading: false})
    })
}
```

When I run `npm run deploy` which is the command to deploy my app to a GitHub static page on https://blenderous.github.io/pokedex/, the page shows a couple of errors:

1. 404 Error that `pokedex.json` is not found
2. "An error occurred: " and the Response object with it's status being 404

When I run `npm run deploy`, the application runs `gh-pages -d build`.

How do I make `pokedex.json` file available in the build folder of GitHub Pages. Manually copying the file doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pokedex.json` file could be added to the `blog-assets` folder that belongs to the `blenderous.github.io` blog (since it's a GitHub pages blog, one has to add the file in the `blog-assets` folder of local version of the blog repository, `git add -A` and `git push origin master`. This file can then be accessed in the `PokeList` class by using the URL https://blenderous.github.io/blog-assets/pokedex.json

For convenience, I have added a `json` folder in the `blog-assets` folder, so the URL would be:
https://blenderous.github.io/blog-assets/json/pokedex.json